# `kubectl logs` returns 0 results, but logs exist on the Node

Tags: kubernetes, logging, amazon-eks, kubectl, log-rotation

I have a healthy, 2/2 Ready Pod that has been running without restarts for over half an hour, on Kubernetes 1.27 through EKS.

When I try to run `kubectl logs -n $MY_NS pod/$MY_POD -c $MY_CONTAINER` on my Apple M1 Max with a `kubectl version` of 1.25, I get no logs. I am able to get logs for other Pods as I would expect.

When I exec into a Pod mounting the Node FS, I can see, in `/var/log/pods/$MY_NS-$MY_POD/$MY_CONTAINER`, logs (including rotations). I copied them with `kubectl cp` to my laptop, and they and the contents look roughly as I'd expect:

```
$ ls -la
total 16M
drwxr-xr-x 7 jrichards  224 Mar 12 15:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 jrichards  224 Mar 12 15:45 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jrichards    0 Mar 12 15:45 0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jrichards 920K Mar 12 15:45 0.log.20240312-212825.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 jrichards 922K Mar 12 15:45 0.log.20240312-212835.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 jrichards 908K Mar 12 15:45 0.log.20240312-212845.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 jrichards  13M Mar 12 15:45 0.log.20240312-212856
```

As you can probably tell from the filenames, the container in question was spamming a crazy number of log lines (the most recent gzip file was rotated after only ~10s, after recording >2k msg/s for ~10s, with an uncompressed file size of 76MiB).

Even so, this is very confusing to me. Why does `kubectl logs` not return the any logged output from this container? I tried the command multiple times.

I was able to find [a kubernetes bugfix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/115702) that's targeted for 1.29 relating to `kubectl logs -f`, but I'm not using `-f`.

I also found [a 2015 kubernetes issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11046) that mentions that ['"kubectl logs" may give empty output'](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11046#issuecomment-120281807) and ['I think we should advise that `kubectl logs` is just a "cache" of some of the logs for a pod'](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11046#issuecomment-120505698). Is this still true?

I have read [the kuberenetes logging guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) as well as [the `kubectl logs` man page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_logs/) and found nothing that mentions any limitations on `kubectl logs`.

My questions:

1. Where can I find details on the limitations of `kubectl logs`?
2. Where can I find details of how Kubernetes handles log rotation?
3. How I should expect files to be formatted and used in `/var/log/containers/$MY_NS-$MY_POD/$MY_CONTAINER`?

Comment: `kubectl is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of kube-apiserver.`
Is it possible to try to upgrade kubectl and see if there is any output (though I don't have high hopes for it)?

One more question to double check, does `kubectl logs -n $MY_NS pod/$MY_POD -c $MY_CONTAINER --previous` output any data?

And regarding documentation about logging in kubernetes, this is a good doc:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#log-rotation

Comment: @WalidGhallab, I do not think that the version is the issue, because I am able to get logs for every other Pod I've looked at. No, `--previous` does not return any data, as the Pod has not restarted. Also, as I linked in my post, I have read that doc. It does not provide any details on how k8s does log rotation, except to say the max file size (which doesn't appear accurate) and the number of rotated files kept.

Comment: I suspect it might be caused by the speed of this being rotated. Can you try `kubectl logs` but with `--limit-bytes=5` this time (to double-check this theory)?

Comment: Let me know when you try the suggestion above.